# CSV data from URL to table

Tags: matlab, csv

How can I convert CSV file to a proper table that has rows and columns, reading the CSV directly from a URL?

```
clc;
clear all;
 
S = {urlread('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/homes.csv')} 

T = array2table(S)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `webread`:

```
data = webread( 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/homes.csv' );
```

This gives you a table variable:

[image: table]

In the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html#bue6uid-options) you can see several choices for the `'ContentType'` option. The default `'auto'` will work in this case, and be identified as a table due to the `.csv` file extension. If you wanted to be over-specific, you could also specify the `'table'` content type as part of the optional web options input to `webread`.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to download the file. And then with `readtable("examples.csv")`, it works with your data:

```
filename = 'C:\temp\homes.csv';
data = readtable(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks but I wish to read directly from an URL.